# Angular 5 - Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on the reactive forms and I am not able to get the specifically the form control which has changed or updated from UI rather getting the whole form .  I tried using valueChanges() but it returns the full form itself rather than giving me the specific changed form control .

I tried using the valueChanges() method but no getting what i am expecting

Comment: did you check the answers , are they work ? for you it's will be great if you provide any feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to specific form control rather than the entier form lie this way

```
this.form.get('userName').valueChanges(value=> console.log('name change',value))
```

you can manage subscribe to form controls dynamically like this

```
this.form = fb.group({
  name: [],
  age: [],
  address: [],
});

Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key  => {
  this.form.get(key).valueChanges.subscribe(value =>{
    console.log(`control ${key} has change =>` ,value)
  })
});
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-value-change)

Comment: HI Malbarmawi , thank you for replying . I was aware that we have to loop over the keys and check if the form control has changed. But i was looking for any particular method of reactive forms , which could only give the changed control as soon there is some change instead  of looping and checking for each form control . Thanks again for the answer

Answer (score 1):

you can still use form `valueChanges` pipe with `pairwise` operator to get the **previous** and **current value** and by compare both values you can get the the controls that changes

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      name: [],
      age: [],
      address: [],
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.
       pipe(debounceTime(2000) ,startWith(null), pairwise()).  
       subscribe(([prev, next]) => {
        if (prev === null) { //  run only first time 
          console.log(this.getValue(next))
        } else { //  compare values
          const result = {};
          const keys = Object.keys(next);

          keys.forEach(key => {
            if (prev[key] !== next[key]) {
              result[key] = next[key]
            }
          });
          console.log(result) ; //  the value that has changed 
        }
      })
  }

  //  
  // for the first time all form controls are null 
  // so this mwthos get the value of object taht has a value 
  getValue(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev: any, key) => {
      if (obj[key]) {
        prev[key] = obj[key];
      };
      return prev;
    }, {})
  }
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-value-change-rfraez)